# SharePoint 2013 - How to search Document Library by filename alone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, as I am searching for a file in Site Collection Documents, it appears that SharePoint is searching results for....

1. an exact match on a file name.
2. matching words within the document of that file.

Is there anything under site settings -> Search, that I can do to tell SharePoint to search document libraries only by file name? and not by content found in each document?

If this would work, the I know I can search filename values like this (i.e. document_*, or like this document_one.pdf).  And I'm ok with that.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using property

```
filename:"Document_whatever"
```

Comment: Amal, I don't know how you figured that out, but you are man!  Thank you!

Comment: Here you go.. Keep it handy.. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tips-for-effective-searches-945991dc-d395-47e2-9e60-40fdf1f9a6ab#bmha10241114_sectipsonpropertiesinsearc

Comment: Many thanks Amal!  I will definitely keep this article by my side!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work if you are looking for a word in the middle of a filename.  For instance, if I look for filename:*current*, Budget_current.xlsx isn't found.  Tried filename:"*current*" too.

Seems like a huge flaw that words in filenames are not found, but words in document content are.

Comment: If you put asteriks on either side of the query, it will return any filename with the text in it with zero or more chars to either side. Microsoft have always had a shoddy implementation of substring searching.

Comment: Did you ever solve this Mike? I'm finding "filename:" searches give very limited results for certain documents. Especially seems this is the case for libraries with version history turned on.

Comment: Actually, after further testing, I think my issue is likely to be around the use of hyphens in filenames. So for 'budget-current.xlsx" both _filename:budget-current_ and _filename:budget*_ would find that document, but I wouldn't find it with _filename:current_.

Answer (score 0):

Use the open with explorer option within SharePoint and then when you search in the windows explorer this should search solely by filename.

Comment: Hi welcome to SP.SE. As you start sharing your knowledge consider reading https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer